# Python standalone .py or external import of module? Is this really as hard as it seems?

Tags: python, pipenv

Situation: I've installed a bunch of packages with pip. I've now written code using these packages.

I have a myscript.py

My friend is on windows.
has python installed.
He has no packages.
He cannot get any packages.
He has pip
He will never be able to use the internet to get more packages everything must be hand delivered. 
In fact about 10 minutes after he runs whatever I give him, he formats his machine and it's gone.

How do I take myscript.py and give it to him on a USB stick so that he can copy the file myscript.py onto his computer and run it?

I thought Pipenv would do it but it looks like it just creates a LIST of packages to download from the internet. (a very well defined list... but a list not the actual files needed to run something. Do I understand it correctly?

Right now I'm giving him .exe made with py2exe. This isn't very elegant considering he has python already.

tl;dr how do I give a python script .py to an end user that doesn't have the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can package everything up in a virtual environment and give him the complete environment necessary to run the script. You can read about this at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Python/Virtualenv and an IDE like PyCharm will help you create such an environment easily.

It's actually a good thing to learn about and do anyway.